# Como renomear uma branch remota e mesma local a partir da remota?

Tags: git

Qual comando deve ser utilizado para renomear um `branch` remota e atualizar o nome da mesma `branch` local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você também pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$ git branch -m nome_antigo nome_novo         # Renomeia o *branch* local   
$ git push origin :nome_antigo                # Deleta o *branch* antigo no repositório remoto (dois pontos + nome do *branch*)    
$ git push --set-upstream origin nome_novo    # Push no novo *branch*
```

Comment: Boa, não conhecia o -m

Answer (score 2):

O nome de uma *branch* no git é somente uma referência, o que vale mesmo é a linha de sequência entre os *commits* juntamente com seus *hashes*.

Então, basta você criar uma nova *branch* com o novo nome:

```
git checkout -b branch-renomeada
```

E em seguida dar um push dessa *branch* (assumindo que seu repositório remoto está como origin):

```
git push origin branch-renomeada
```

Depois disso, se você quiser pode apagar a *branch* antiga:

```
git branch -D branch-antiga
```

Para remover a *branch* remota com nome antigo, caso você já tenha dado um push anteriormente:

```
git push origin :branch-antiga
```